# mongodb php findone() by ID

Tags: php, mongodb

This code will not find a record based on an ID search

```
<?php

$userid = $_GET['id'];

$theObjId = new MongoId($userid); 

$connection = new Mongo('localhost');

$db = $connection->test->items; 

$item = $db->findOne(array('_id' => $theObjId));

echo 'Item: ' . $item . '<br>';

echo 'UserID: ' . $userid . '<br>';

echo 'TheObjID: ' . $theObjId;

$connection->close(); 

?>
```

$userid is supplied by a form in another .php file

This is the output ....

```
$item: Array

 $userid: 4e0dfc8e7bfb8bac12000000

 $theObjId: 4e0dfc8e7bfb8bac12000000
```

the output proves my variables contain the ID

Answer (score 7):

I just had to do this, and didn't think the other answers answered the question.

Simply put, to query by Mongo ID (the `_id` field), use the [MongoId](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php) object, then use the [iterator_to_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php) function, which effectively copies the iterator into an array suitable for iteration:

```
<?php

    $doc_id = "4f917f15168cbe6364000032";

    $cursor = $collection->find(
        array(
            '_id' => new MongoId($doc_id)
        )
    );

    $cursor2array = iterator_to_array($cursor);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($cursor2array); echo "</pre>";

    foreach ( $cursor2array[$doc_id] as $key => $value )
    {
         echo "$key => $value <br/>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: You can simply use `findOne` and there is no need to use `iterator_to_array`. The key is to use `MongoId` in the query.

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB needs integer variable to create the right query.

In my project it works like this :

```
<?php
$id = (int)$_GET["id"]; 
$cursor = $this->connect()->$db->$collection->find(array('_id' => $id));
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: How does `(int)$_GET["id"]; ` and `(string)$_GET["id"]; ` are different from each other ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using this the [official driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/)  then you should use this

```
$item = $db->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($userid));
```

Answer (score 2):

`$item` is an array. so print `$item` as below..

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($item);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

This post is a little stale, but in case anybody is researching this issue, here are a couple items to consider:

1)  $item is an Array, so the code should probably read something more like this:

```
echo 'Item: ' . $item['name'] . '<br>';
```

2)  also, the userid and itemid seem to be conflated in the original post.  A more common pattern would be to set a 'uid' field in the items collection, so it has both an '_id' and 'uid' fields.  Such as this:

```
$item = $db->find(array('uid' => $userid));
```

3) in this pattern, sometimes I find I need to cast the ObjectID or MongoID to a string, as follows:

```
$item = $db->findOne(array('uid' => (string)$userid));
```

4) but for a simple _id search, this is all you should need:

```
$item = $db->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($userid));
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Does the result ($item) have the "_id" in it?

```
echo $item['_id'];
```